# Holomorphic function convergent sequence , proof identically zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Theorem attached and proof.[image]

I am stuck on

1) Where we get $|g(z)|\geq |a_m|/2 $ comes from 
so $a_{m}$ is the first non-zero fourier coeffient. So I think this term is $< |a_m|r^{m}$, from $r$ the radius of the open set, but I don't know how to take care of the rest of the higher terms through $a_{m}$ , is this some theorem or?

2) The conclusion thus $f(z)$ has only one zero at $z=z_0$
I think i'm being stupid but what is this being made from?
We know $g(z_0) = a_{m} \neq 0 $ and $a_{0}=0$, but I dont understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) follows just from the definition of continuity. You don't need to worry about the other Taylor series coefficients. Note that $g(z_0) = a_m$, so by continuity $\lim_{z\to z_0}g(z) = a_m$. By definition, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $r > 0$ such that $\vert z - z_0 \vert < r$ implies 
$$\vert g(z) - a_m \vert < \epsilon,$$
i.e.
$$\vert a_m \vert - \epsilon < \vert g(z) \vert < \vert a_m \vert + \epsilon.$$
Setting $\epsilon = \tfrac{\vert a_m \vert}{2},$ we conclude that
$$\vert g(z) \vert > \frac{\vert a_m\vert}{2}$$
whenever $\vert z - z_0 \vert < r$.

2) Using 1), we conclude that throughout the disk $\vert z - z_0 \vert < r$, we have
$$\vert f(z) \vert = \vert (z - z_0)^m g(z)\vert \geq \vert z - z_0\vert^m \frac{\vert a_m \vert}{2}.$$
The expression on the right clearly has only one zero in this disk (namely $z = z_0$), so the same is true of $f$.

Comment: apologies actually, how do we know both f and g are continous? edit: oh holomorphic implies continous at every point where the function is defined?

Comment: correct, if $f$ is holomorphic at a point $z$, then $f$ is continuous at $z$.